# How to enable offline access to customer data in google adwords api php

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

Google Adwords API (PHP Client)

I am trying to get a user to authorize once on my website to be able to get his data for analytical purposes. But I can not figure out a way to do it with the documentation it is quite complex.

Do I need to add them to my mcc to be able to do this or is there another way using something like https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to connect the user via oauth token with offline access activated, so that the request returns a refresh token, that you can use to programmatically access the connection, even if the user is not logged into you application:

```
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

As explained here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication you can use the oauth playground from groogle to test the api and see what you need.

Additionally here is an example for the client connection method (partially Laravel specific code, but should be good enough to explain the procedure):

```
function googleIntegrationClient($refresh=false)
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(env('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'));
    $client->setApplicationName('App Google Integration');
    $client->addScope("profile");
    $client->addScope("email");
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords");

    //make sure there is a refresh token in the request for offline access.
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    if($refresh)
    {
        //get currently logged in user
        $user = \Auth::user();
        //set token from user data
        $client->setAccessToken($user->settings["integration"]["google"]['token_data']);

        //check if token is valid
        if($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
        {
            //as token is invalid set refresh token
            $token_data = json_decode($user->settings["integration"]["google"]['token_data']);
            $client->refreshToken($token_data->refresh_token);

            //save new token data
            $modify_settings = $user->settings;
            $modify_settings["integration"]["google"]["token_data"] = $client->getAccessToken();
            $user->settings = $modify_settings;
            $user->save();
        }
    }

    return $client;
}
```

You can use this method then in your oauth connecting routine:

```
//route for redirecting to google oauth
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    $user = \Auth::User();
    $client = googleIntegrationClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    return \Redirect::to(filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

//callback route to handle the provided data from google oauth
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
 $user = \Auth::User();
 $client = googleIntegrationClient();
 $data = $request->all();
 if (isset($data['code']))
 {
     try {
         $client->authenticate($data['code']);
         $token = $client->getAccessToken();
     } catch (Exception $e) {
         $user->settings = array(
             "integration" => array(
                 "google" => array(
                     'active' => false,
         )));
         $user->save();
     }

     if($token)
     {
         $google_oauth = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

         $user->settings = array(
             "integration" => array(
                 "google" => array(
                     'active' => true,
                     'token_data' => $token,
                     'id' => $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->id,
                     'avatar' => $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->picture,
                     'email' => $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->email,
                     'name' => $google_oauth->userinfo->get()->name,
         )));
         $user->save();
     }
 }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate, the Auth:user class is that a class from the api ? also google_client class?

Comment: Auth::user is from laravel, essentially just a class that provides you with the currently logged in user of your app, which has nothign to do with the connection to google – this example just shows how to persist the connection to google with the currently logged in user. google_client is from the php api.

Comment: also, I should mention that I am still using the google-api-php-client in version 1.*. If you are using 2.* some commands might vary, but it will be the same mechanism.

Comment: For details on the differences between version 1 and 2 of google-api-php-client please check out: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md

Comment: I am using the adwords api which is slightly different but I got it to work by going through the libraries.